How can I display error message for Commerce order after returning false for isValid on ModelEvent?
I'm trying to modify the behavior around updating a Commerce order's status to Cancelled so that a third-party integration is checked first to see if it's safe to cancel, then proceeds accordingly. Below is a simplified version of the code in my module.
Event::on(
    Order::class,
    Order::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE,
    function(ModelEvent $event) {
        /** @var Order $order */
        $order = $event->sender;

        // determine if order can be cancelled

        if ($canCancelOrder) {
            return;
        }

        $order->addError('orderStatusId', 'Cannot cancel order with status “My Order Status”.');
        $event->isValid = false;
    }
);

After attempting to change the status on an item that should not be cancelled, it does not save the updated status, as expected. However, the Commerce order edit page doesn't display any errors set on the order, and the flash message is vague:

Couldn’t save order.

I'd like to find a way to display errors on the order edit page after isValid on the ModelEvent returns false and make the flash message more specific. Is this possible?
